# How can I manage nested transaction using TransactionScope() In ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have created a transaction inside the transaction within a main transaction scope using

```
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)
```

but my problem is, when inner transaction is successfully committed, then if any error is occurred during the execution, then my full transaction is not rollback completely,

means, my inner transaction records are there in my database.
but I want that my full transaction rollback.

Help me if any solution is there for this kind of situation.

Comment: Take a look at *Nested Transactions* here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971557.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't request a *new* transaction. Say `Required` and the scope simply attaches to the existing transaction.